# Django project setup issue with the command : django-admin startproject xxxxxx

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I started coding in python - Django just few days ago .I am using windows 10 .

I installed Django project with pip and virtual env.

but when I give this command :  `django-admin startproject xxxxxx`

the console is showing : `Command not found: django-admin.py`

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: What have you tried out so far? Have you activated your virtual environment? To activate it `cd` to your project folder and enter `source bin/activate`.
What does `which python` returns? Also, what does `pip list | grep "django"` return?
If you cannot use grep, just try `pip list` and search for django. 
Have looked up the general django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/windows/#setting-up-a-virtual-environment
If that's not helping you much you could also find some infos in the python guide:  https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 0):

Your commands are looking fine .

So do these things :

1. Check if django and virtual env  is installed correctly.
2. If not , then , remove virtual environment , reinstall it , then install django .
3. Run the command again.

If you till facing the issue , let me know by comment.